# Learn Bootstrap for Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Suggest me Good Site for Exploring twitter-Bootstrap (For my Rails Application).
Suggest some site from where I can get snip codes and use them in my Application 
    with little modifications as per my need.

```
I have got following links handy, other than those Suggest something better:

 http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
 http://bootply.com/60390
```

Comment: The bootstrap documentation is the best source for this. It explains all of its classes fairly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Rails, I'd suggest you look at & then use the Rails gem:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

I agree with @MitulP91 above that the Bootstrap documentation is the best starting place for how it works

Also, look at Ryan's Railcasts and start with this article (there are others in the series I think):

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics
```

On the gem documentation page there is a link to a working example also

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is only used for front-end beautification or for a better UX.  I doubt anyone would've even written a blog or articles with rails specific examples with bootstrap in action. If there is one it wouldn't really matter. Because it is completely independent of what scripting framework you're using. Go through the bootstrap documentation [Getting Started](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html) (the link you've provided in your question), and that is the best way to get you started.

That being said, you may want to create static HTML documents and explore each of the plugins that ships with bootstrap to better understand them and then include bootstrap specific javascript code in a separate `.js` file under your javascript directory of your rails app, to better structure them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you to explore twitter bootstrap

[Click Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial-handling-complex-designs/)